# VMWare REST Api - access VM host details via REST API

Tags: rest, vmware

I'm using the VMWare REST API (/api/vcenter/host) to query information about the VM Hosts registered on a vCenter.  At the moment I can only seem to get basic info like this :

```
{
  "host": "host-10",
  "name": "192.168.18.89",
  "connection_state": "CONNECTED",
  "power_state": "POWERED_ON"
}
```

but the Powershell "Get-VMHost | Format-List" has much more useful information such as ESXi version, hardware specs etc.

[image]

Can I get this kind of information via the REST API as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can get that kind of information, depending on exactly what info you are wanting. The REST API references are here that you can use to look up what you need. https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/

For example if you want to know what software is installed you can do something like this.

```
export basepw=$(echo -n 'administrator@vsphere.local:{password}' | base64)

export token3=$(curl -k -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic ${basepw}" https://{vCenterIP}/api/session/ | tr -d '"')

curl -k -X GET -H "vmware-api-session-id: ${token}" "https://{vCenterIP}/api/esx/software" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_type": "EXISTING", "host": "{host-##}"}' | jq .
```

It looks like vSphere 8 has more options that might fit what you want, like extracting the config https://developer.vmware.com/apis/vsphere-automation/latest/esx/settings/hosts.configuration/

From the looks, some other SDKs would be more developed that the REST API current state. Personally I like govmomi and pyvmomi and both have a CLI tool that can get you started pretty fast. The cli tool for govmomi, govc, doesn't require anything extra to run, so it is fairly portable and might help you with what you are doing.
https://github.com/vmware/govmomi
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi